# Can't see my response to a tweet. Am I blocked?

Tags: twitter

Whenever I respond to a tweet of a person I'm following on Twitter, I am able to see my reply when I click on the original tweet of the person I follow.

**But** when I’m not logged into Twitter and look at the original tweet, my response isn't even listed. Is it possible that the person blocked me on Twitter or something? Why can I only see my reply when I'm logged in?

Comment: If you were blocked, you wouldn't see the tweet when you were logged in

Answer (score 2):

If you're @replying to a person on Twitter, only that person and that person's followers will see the tweet. Non-followers or anonymous people won't see it.

If you want to @reply to someone and have the world see it, the general convention is to put a period (`.`) in front of the @reply. Like so:

```
.@teamrocket I see what you did there!
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they have you on mute so that is why you only see it when you are logged in? Not sure if that is what happens when someone is on mute.

One thing to note, are you sure you are clicking on tweets & replies and not just tweets when viewing your tweets when you are not logged in?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like mute. [Check official description](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20171399-muting-users-on-twitter)

> Mute is a feature that allows you to remove an account's Tweets from your timeline without unfollowing or blocking that account. Muted accounts will not know that you’ve muted them and you can unmute them at any time